# Unity3D doesn't work on an Acer Aspire One XG5 with Intel graphics

Tags: unity, drivers, intel-graphics

I have Ubuntu 12.04 LTS Beta on an Acer Aspire One ZG5 net book with a Mobile Intel 945 Express Chip-set Family card.

I've installed Ubuntu 11.04 last year two days before the release of 11.10. Right after I installed the KDE Plasma Desktop, my graphics fell off a cliff.

Unity started putting me on 2D mode, Gnome on classic, and on KDE I had to use X render. Months after searching for graphics problems I found out that when I went to "Details" in System Settings, the list for graphics showed NONE! I tried searching for Intel drivers, but that's like searching for Gold on a sidewalk.

Even when I do find some sort of driver, I can't find a way to use it. The Additional drivers list would not help either.

I have three other operating systems:

- Windows 7
- Linux Mint
- Pinguy OS

Those ones don't have any problems with my card. I upgraded from 11.10 to 12.04 LTS beta in hope of Canonical including my card in their driver list, and again it didn't work.

I'd appreciate anyone's word on this.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! This question should instead be filed as a bug report, thanks! [Instructions here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug).

Comment: YAHOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO!!!!!!! I fiXed it

Comment: i fixed it by going to linux mint and checking the package manager for opengl files and i went to ubuntu to apply installation of missing files!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: Please post this as an answer so the next person can benefit. If you can show the list of things you installed that would be great.

Answer (score 3):

Please Let Me Ask solved the problem in a comment:

> I fixed it by going to Linux Mint and checking the package manager for openGL files and I went to Ubuntu to apply installation of missing files!!!!!!!!!!!

[– Please let me ask May 8 '12 at 16:00](https://askubuntu.com/questions/128167/unity3d-doesnt-work-on-an-acer-aspire-one-xg5-with-intel-graphics#comment159192_128167)

Comment: The answer to my problem was that my updates for kde probably uninstalled OpenGL....